# How do I validate a first character must begin with A-Z

Tags: php, validation

In PHP how do I validate user input like an example below.

Example valid input

```
$input ='abkc32453';
$input ='a32453';
$input ='dsjgjg';
```

Example invalid input

```
$input ='2sdf23';
$input ='2121adsasadf';
$input ='23142134';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z]/i', $input)) { /*   "/i" means case independent */
    ...
}
```

or use `[:alpha:]` if you'd rather not use `[a-z]` (e.g. if you need to recognise accented characters).

Answer (score 6):

```
if(ctype_alpha($input[0])){
//first character is alphabet
}
else {
//first character is invalid
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might try using a regular expression, with the [**`preg_match()`**](https://www.php.net/preg_match) function :

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]/', $input)) {
    // input is OK : starts with a letter
}
```

Basically, you search for :

- beginning of string : `^`
- one letter : `[a-zA-Z]`

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('%^[a-zA-Z].*%', $input, $matches);
```